# Nodejs module executing the code multiple times

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I googled various resources and all of them says nodejs run's the module once in require call yet I am getting different result.

Here is the piece of code in a module named socketio.

```
var sio = require("socket.io");
var io = sio.listen(3001);
module.exports = io;
```

The thing is , if I execute the code below

```
var io = require(socketio);
io = require(socketio);
```

I get the error `listen EADDRINUSE :::3001` , But I suppose the code shouldn't have run twice and the previous io object should have been returned , but no avail.

I am requiring the socket twice because I need socketio for two different features of my application in two different files.

I also tried the below code where I try to design a singleton which didn't work too and the same error.

```
var sio = null;
var io  = null;
module.exports = function () {

    if(io == null) {
        sio = require("socket.io");
        io = sio.listen(3001);
    }
    return io;

};
```

Comment: Why are you requiring it twice? In any case, `io` will always be null in your "workaround" because you set it to null--that's not the condition you should be checking.

Comment: I need the socket in two different part of my application , this requiring twice is just a simpler version. Editing my post though

Comment: But I suppose according to http://fredkschott.com/post/2013/12/node-js-cookbook---designing-singletons/ second time require should return the cached object without running the code.

Comment: can you try with another port 9090 or else. Or confirm 3001 is not used by any other application: Your first example should work.

Comment: I see now ,It was because I was running the two files separately in my IDE. .. The issue is resolved now. Thanks.